# Problems rqt_plot array

Tags: ros, rostopic-echo, rqt-plot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I am trying to plot a topic **/mytopic/taskSpace/position[0]** using rqt_plot. My ROS version is Indigo and I have Ubuntu 14.

When I type in the console **rostopic echo /mytopic/taskSpace/position[0]** I can see the values, but when I make
**rosrun rqt_plot rqt_plot /mytopic/taskSpace/position[0]** The values are not plot. Also there is not errors in the console. Even when I add again the same topic, the console shows **PlotWidget.add_topic(): topic already subscribed: /mytopic/taskState/position[0]**

I don't know how to solve this and it would be very usefull for me since I need to plot a lot of topic in order to check my code.

Than you so much!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236370/problems-rqt_plot-array/) by [azul azul](https://answers.ros.org/users/27065/azul-azul/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2016-06-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I could find the solution. For someone with the same problem, it is necessary to fill the time stamp data in the message

**msg.header.stamp = ros::Time::now()**

---

Originally posted by [azul azul](https://answers.ros.org/users/27065/azul-azul/) with karma: 26 on 2016-06-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Additionally, you can use PlotJuggler: https://github.com/facontidavide/PlotJuggler

There is an option, when you load a rosbag to either use the msg.header.stamp or the time when the message was received.

---

Originally posted by [Davide Faconti](https://answers.ros.org/users/578/davide-faconti/) with karma: 308 on 2018-01-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1